# How to get uid in response from admin-sdk collection in firestore

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

The following code works great to retrieve all the items in the collection. However, the uids are not available here and I need them to be able to compare with other userRefs.

```
app.get("/api/all-users", (req, res) => {
  let arr = [], i = 0;
  db.collection('users').get()
     .then((result) => {
        result.forEach((doc) => {
          arr[i] = doc.data();
            i++
         })
        res.json(arr);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err);
     })
})
```

This returns a json response:

```
users: [
  {name: 'Name', username: 'Username' etc ..}
]
```

However I was looking for something with the actual uids. How would I get that information with a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the **document ID** where you say *uid* (which is typically used to denote a *user* ID).

Since you only return `doc.data()` you are dropping the document ID. If you want to return both, you could do:

```
app.get("/api/all-users", (req, res) => {
  let arr = [], i = 0;
  db.collection('users').get()
     .then((result) => {
        result.forEach((doc) => {
          arr[i] = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
          i++
         })
        res.json(arr);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err);
     })
})
```

Or a simpler version of the same:

```
db.collection('users').get()
   .then((result) => {
      res.json(result.docs.map(doc => { 
        return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
      });
   })
```

Comment: Thank you. exactly what I was missing.